# dplyr: Send all Columns to a function within a mutate following a group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the preferred way to send all columns within a current group to a function as a tibble or data.frame when calling an arbitrary function in a dplyr pipe?

In the example below, `mean_B` is a simple example where I know what is needed before I make the function call.  `mean_B_fun` gives the wrong answer (compared to what I want-- I want the within-group mean), and `mean_B_fun_ugly` gives what I want, but it seems like both an inefficient (and ugly) way to get the effect I want.

The reason I want to operate on arbitrary columns is that in practice, I'm taking `my_fun` in the example below from the user, and I don't know the columns that the user will need to operate on a priori.

```
library(dplyr)

my_fun <- function(x) mean(x$B)

my_data <-
  expand.grid(A=1:3, B=1:2) %>%
  mutate(B=A*B) %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(mean_B=mean(B),
         mean_B_fun=my_fun(.),
         mean_B_fun_ugly=my_fun(as.data.frame(.)[.$A == unique(A),,drop=FALSE]))
```

Comment: `mutate_all` will apply a function, by group, to all columns other than the grouping columns. For `my_fun`, the argument `x` should be a vector and the operation in the function would be `mean(x)`, since mutate will pass a vector of values from a given column.

Comment: There are basically two types of functions in `tidyverse`: 1) those that take a dataframe as a first argument (used in pipes, e.g. tidyr::separate or dplyr::top_n) and 2) those that take vectors (e.g. all functions in `stringr` or many `base` functions, such as `mean`, `max`, `sum`) - these are typically used in `mutate` statements. There are some that can take either df or vector (like `purrr::map`), but the behaviour will be different. Your user-function should be type 2 - it should take a vector, not a dataframe. Assuming user does not subset inside the function, `group_by` will be honored.

Comment: @eipi10 The user may need to apply a function to multiple columns to get the output of their function.  In general, what is written as `mean(x$B)` could alternatively be `mean(x$B) + mean(x$A)`, and I wouldn't know which columns they need.

Comment: @dmi3kno, "Your user-function should... take a vector, not a dataframe."  I can't make that restriction on my users.  In one function call, they may need column `A`, and in the next function call they may need column `B`, and in the next function call they may need both `A` and `B`.  More generally, I don't know all the column names in the user's dataset, what they will mean to the user, and which will be important.

Answer (score 0):

here's my answer, not knowing the columns on which you want to calculate the mean.

```
expand.grid(A=1:3, B=1:2) %>%
mutate(B=A*B) %>% nest(-A)  %>%
mutate(means = map(.$data, function(x) colMeans(x)))

  A data means
1 1 1, 2   1.5
2 2 2, 4     3
3 3 3, 6   4.5
```

Comment: This solution doesn't pass the entire data.frame into colMeans; it only appears to pass column `B`.

Comment: It will pass all the columns you are not grouping on :)