# R dplyr::mutate pass all columns using "." but limit rows by group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure this has been answered already somewhere here, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm using dplyr, and am trying to pass all columns in a data frame to a custom function using *mutate*, but limit the input rows by *group_by*.  I'm guessing the "." operator is not the way to go, but what else might be recommended?

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:4,each = 5),y= rnorm(20))

myfunc <- function(df) {
       print(paste(nrow(df),ncol(df)))
       return(mean(df$x))
}

df  %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y = myfunc(.))
```

Actual output is below, indicating that it's passing the whole data frame to the function 4 times.

```
[1] "20 2"
[1] "20 2"
[1] "20 2"
[1] "20 2"
```

I was hoping for an output like below, i.e. passing each subset of the data frame to the custom function:

```
[1] "5 2"
[1] "5 2"
[1] "5 2"
[1] "5 2"
```

How do I conveniently pass all columns to my function but still get the group_by to work?

Thanks

Comment: Look at `mutate_all`

Comment: It seems like you should be using `do()` here: `df  %>% group_by(x) %>% do(data.frame(x=.$x, y=myfunc(.)))`

Comment: There's also the `nest()` approach. See this possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894771/dplyr-send-all-columns-to-a-function-within-a-mutate-following-a-group-by

Comment: @MrFlick  Thanks...that's the solution.  I'm not sure I understand the .$x call, but I'll investigate further the do documentation.

Comment: You first need to define what you want to do with your grouped variable! You could do something like .. %>% summarise (n=n(), m = mean(x))!

Comment: @tobiaspk1  So this is a situation where I don't actually want to reduce the data frame to a single row for each group_by variable value...for each row, I want to calculate a new value based on all the columns with a subset of rows....